# ImageMagick can't use JPEG (OSX/X11)?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

Trying to give RMagick a whirl, using Mac OSX and homebrew.

Versions:
Mac OSX 10.7.5, HomeBrew 0.9.4., Ruby 2.0, Rmagick 2.13.2, ImageMagick 6.8.6-3.

Here is my Ruby code, in a file named `rename.rb`:

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

cat = ImageList.new("test.jpg")
cat.display
exit
```

and here is my terminal output:

```
rename.rb:5:in `display': delegate library support not built-in `test.jpg' (X11) @ error/display.c/DisplayImages/16067 (Magick::ImageMagickError)
    from rename.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

It seems though I have the proper delegates installed (I'm not entirely sure, however, since I'm a n00b at ImageMagick).  If I run `convert -list configure`, I get this:

```
...
DELEGATES      bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jpeg png rsvg tiff xml zlib
...
```

any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image has been read and processed successfully, your error is being thrown by `cat.display` It is not an image format delegate missing, but a window display one.

You will see the same error message on the command line if you simply type:

```
display test.jpg
```

So this is an Image Magick issue, not an RMagick or Ruby one.

It seems that the `display` method is designed to work with X11 windowing, which is not a default feature on Mac OS X. You may be able to re-build it including an X11 service and libary. I use XQuartz for X11 support, but installing it *after* Image Magick (as I did) won't fix this issue. So, I get same error as you, but I don't use `display`, I just use a command like `open test.jpg` on the command line, or:

```
`open test.jpg`
```

from Ruby. This is not a platform-agnostic solution, but I can view the images I process just fine.

Alternatively, you could try re-installing Image Magick and rmagick with X11 support (provided of course that you have an X11 service installed such as XQuartz):

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --with-x11
gem install rmagick
```

I have tested this, and it works to so that `cat.display` will launch a display window. Although I think I will continue to use other viewers myself.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to actually uninstall `imagemagick` before reinstalling with X11.